# i can only see blacky images while importing fbx file in blender

Tags: materials, export, import

I have a textured model in blender. i tried to export it as a fbx file. and again I opened the fbx file in blender. after i importing i can only see **full black body images not textured**. could you please any one help me to solve this issue[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try opening each of those materials in the node editor to see what's going on. Sometimes when you export models made in other programs, one thing or another is lost in translation.

Make sure all the textures are plugged in where they should be - into the respective inputs in the shader node - and see if that helps.

I've had to adapt materials in imported assets in a similar way myself. Hope that helps!

Comment: sorry i made it in blender only

Comment: @ManojKumarerd, it's still worth looking at the materials to make sure everything is present and correctly plugged in. The 'lost in translation' bit can also occur during the export/import process, what with the multitude of options.